# How do I ensure I'm writing my output JSON files in UTF-8?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to write my output JSON files in Python to UTF-8. However, I am not sure if I am doing it correctly and I'm not sure how to verify the output is in utf-8. I am calling:

```
json_output = json.dump(new_json, outfile, ensure_ascii = False)
```

where new_json is my data.

Will this encode in UTF-8?

Comment: Open the result in a text editor set to interpret the file as UTF-8. Is the text readable? Great. To really answer your question we'd need to see how `outfile` was opened…

Comment: Although I'm being pedantic, I do want to note that not all unicode characters are valid JSON...

Answer (score 0):

something like?

```
   with open('myfile.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
        json.dump(new_json, outfile)
```